# Using JQuery to redirect to a third party page and prefill form values

Tags: jquery, redirect

When clicked on a link on my web page, I want to redirect to third party web page (like google) and prefill the search window with my query and simulate clicks.

Is it possible to do with just jquery?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need any JavaScript for that (that is, when you want to simulate the click, too).

I assume, you want to have something like a custom search box. Then open up Google's front page and look at the source code (which is quite a mess, I suggest Firebug for this).

Search the HTML `<form>` that is responsible for the form field and all containing `<input>` fields. If the `<form>` element has this attribute: `method="GET"` (or no `method` at all), you can just combine all other inputs but `q` in the URL (the `action` attribute) of the form by collapsing them like `"a=b&c=d"`.

Then write your own form on your website, or even just a simple link (since links are nothing more than get requests to other pages, in this case you will also have to add the `q`, too).

Tadaa! Your own submit form to Google.